# Can someone help me understand what the problem is? its not showing the data correctly in the RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

when the app is run everything is fine except that the data (Text) does not show how it's supposed to.
It was working fine when the first run the app with this code but when I was making amendments to the code it somehow stopped displaying the data the I way I wanted and I can't find out why this is happening. I even undid all the amendments but it still will not work.

This is my Main just in case

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("DefaultWords");

EditText engText, araText;
Button submitBtn, display, deletebtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    writeToData();
    disButton();



}


private void writeToData() {


    engText = findViewById(R.id.english);
    araText = findViewById(R.id.arabic);
    submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.button);

    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String engWord = engText.getText().toString().trim();
            String araWord = araText.getText().toString().trim();


            MyWords words = new MyWords(engWord, araWord);


            myRef.child(engWord).setValue(words);


        }
    });

}
```

}

My Adapter

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {


    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private List<MyWords> words;


    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyWords> words) {
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.words = words;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_custom_cards, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        MyWords words1 = words.get(position);

        holder.englishText.setText(words1.getEnglish());
        holder.arabicText.setText(words1.getArabic());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return words.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView englishText, arabicText;


        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            englishText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardTextView);
            arabicText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardTextView2);
        }
    }
```

my RecyclerView

```
public class RecylePractice extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("DefaultWords");



    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Adapter adapter;
    ArrayList<MyWords> wordsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_recyle_view);


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyle);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new Adapter(this, wordsArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recylerReadData();


    }


    private void recylerReadData() {


        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    MyWords words = postSnapshot.getValue(MyWords.class);


                    wordsArrayList.add(words);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());


            }
        });
    }
}
```

**this is what happen the display is run**

[image: this is what happen the display is run]

I wanted the English words to display on the left and the Arabic words to display on the right.

my new_custom_cards xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#CCDFA6A6"
android:padding="10dp"

>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView_custom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/english"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@color/red"

            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardTextView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/arabic"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/eqauls123"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardTextView2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: first move  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); outside for loop

Comment: @Md. Asaduzzaman 24, how do i add additional code?? I'm new :/

Comment: Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60039068/edit) and add required code

Comment: @ Md. Asaduzzaman, just added it

Comment: Try to set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in your `RecyclerView`

Comment: @ Md. Asaduzzaman , that worked THANKS, how do I upvote your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `wrap_content` as `layout_width` in your `RecyclerView`. Try to change it `match_parent` like below

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

You did set wrap_content in your itemview layout width.

Comment: Your item view layout ok,I think your recycler view width wrap_content .

Answer (score 0):

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                MyWords words = postSnapshot.getValue(MyWords.class);


                wordsArrayList.add(words);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
```

REPLACE ABOVE CODE WITH BELOW CODE

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    MyWords words = postSnapshot.getValue(MyWords.class);


                    wordsArrayList.add(words);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```